# javascript logic error where my html .text() not replacing old text on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

so this is looping twice and I have no idea why? I'm pretty sure its a logic error but I've tried everything I can. I want the output of the roman numeral to be replaced by a new roman numeral when submit is clicked.

```
var romanSymbols = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"];
var numbers = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
var result = " ";
var replaceNum = function(_userInput) {
  for (var index = 0; index < numbers.length; index += 1) {
    while (numbers[index] <= _userInput) {
      result += romanSymbols[index];
      _userInput -= numbers[index];

    }
    debugger;
  }
  return result;
}

$(function(){
 $("form").submit(function(event){
  var userInput = $("#numOnly").val();
  var romanNumeral = replaceNum(userInput);
  $("#result").text(replaceNum);

  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "looping twice"? What exactly is it doing, and what is the desired result?

Comment: Prepares the code $("#result").text(replaceNum); would be  $("#result").text(romanNumeral);

Comment: So when you input your number it should output a Roman numeral and when submit is clicked it should get rid of the old Roman numeral with the new one, but instead it just adds the new one after the old one. So instead of replacing XII with XIX it adds it so the output is XIIXIX

Answer (score 0):

The result needs to be placed inside of your method you are adding to it each time you call the method thats why the first time it works and from then on it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be replacing the text with `romanNumeral` instead of `replaceNum`?

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        var userInput = $("#numOnly").val();
        var romanNumeral = replaceNum(userInput);
        $("#result").text(romanNumeral); //changed this from replaceNum

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```